# Can a variable go to a hidden PHP page using jQuery?

Tags: php, jquery, variables

My PHP page

```
<ul id="upvote-the-image">
<li><a href="javascript:return false;" rel="50" id="upvote">Upvote</a><img src="image.png" /></li>
</ul>​
```

is currently successfully sending variable to javascript

```
$("#upvote").each(function(index) {
var upthis = $(this).attr("rel");
var plusone = upthis;
$.post("upvote.php", {
    'plusone': plusone
});
alert(plusone);
});​
```

(The alert in the code is for testing)
I have multiple images using the rel tag. I would like for each to be able to be upvoted and shown that they are upvoted on the page without loading a new page.

My question, and problem: what is my next step? I would just like to know how to send a value to upvote.php. I know how touse mysql to add an upvote, just not how to send a value to upvote.php, or even if my javascript code opens the page correctly.

thanks

Comment: you are already sending a key/value pair to upvote.php so that part of question hard to understtand. You must change repeating ID's to class, can't repeat ID in a page

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this:

```
<ul id="upvote-the-image">
    <li><span rel="50" id="upvote">Upvote</span><img src="image.png" /></li>
</ul>​
<span id="result"></span>

$("#upvote").click(function(index) {
  var upthis = $(this).attr("rel");
  var oOptions = {
url:    upvote.php, //the receiving data page
    data: upthis, //the data to the server
    complete: function() { $('#result').text('Thanks!') }  //the result on the page
  };
  $.ajax(oOptions);
}
```

You dont need an anchor, I changed it for a span, you can test asyc connection using F12 in your browser

Comment: need to send key/value pair to server...not just value

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript never opens the php page, it just sends data to it, and receives an http header with a response.  Your php script should be watching for `$_POST['plusone']` and handle database processing accordingly.  Your next step would be to write a callback within your `$.post` function, which I recommend changing to the full ajax function while learning, as it's easier to understand and see all the pieces of what's happening.

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: "upvote.php",
data: {'plusone': plusone},
success: function(IDofSelectedImg){
    //function to increment the rel value in the image that was clicked
      $(IDofSelectedImg).attr("rel")= upthis +1;
      },

});
```

You'd need some unique identifier for each img element in order to select it, and send it's id to the php script.  add a class instead of id for `upvote` and make the id a uniquely identifiable number that you could target with jquery when you need to increment the rel value.  (From the looks of it, It looks like you're putting the value from the rel attribute into the database in the place of the old value.)

Comment: You don't explain where `plusone` comes from which is the other half of the question...

Comment: see his original post for that... and stop stalking me.

Answer (score 0):

A good programming tip here for JQuery, Don't do:

```
<a href="javascript:return false;"
```

Instead do something like:

```
$(function(){
    $('#upvote').on('click', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $.post('upvote.php', {'plusone': $(this).attr('rel')}, function(data){
          alert('done and upvoted');
        });
    });
});
```

That is a much better way to handle links on your DOM document.

Here are some Doc pages for you to read about that coding I use:

- http://api.jquery.com/on/
- http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Those will explain my code to you.

Hope it helps,